# MATLAB: Time series plot for n days

Tags: matlab, plot, time, series, scatter

I am trying to do a scatter plot, with the x-axis occupying a range of 5 to 15 in steps of 0.25 and the y-axis occupying 41 random data for 20 days.

```
clc
clear
x = 5:0.25:15;
y = rand(41,20);
```

How can i achieve a scatter plot on MATLAB, whereby the x-range is applicable to all the 20 columns?

Comment: `plot(x, y, 'kx')`?

Comment: `for n = 1:20
t=5:0.25:15;
scatter(t,y(:,n));
hold on
end`

Comment: Is the above code correct for performing the task? also how do i perform the second-order best fit polynomial on MATLAB of the generated plot?

Comment: The code you just pasted produces a scatter plot with 20 x values, each `x` having 41 uniformly distributed numbers with it. The plot is random, you wouldn't gain any information at all from using a command like `polyfit` to do a polynomial fit.

Comment: How do i modify the code to produce the desired scatter plot?

Comment: The code produces a scatter plot. What do you mean by 'desired scatter plot'? What do you want the code to actually do?

Comment: I want the code to produce a scatter plot with x-axis having a range of 5 to 15 and the y-axis to have 41 random data for 20 columns. I.e. the x-range is applicable for the 20 columns.

Comment: Both your code and mine do that. What's the problem with it?

Comment: The code does not go column to column.

Comment: On the same axis or separate subplots?

Comment: On the same axes.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code you posted in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you possibly want a scatter plot with connected lines so that you could identify the different datasets? Here I used the same for-loop approach and holding the plot using `hold on`. In the line `plot(t,y(:,n),'.-');` the term `'.-'` is used to indicate to plot the data with connected lines and dots at the data points. As the comment above indicated for a random dataset doing a best fit polynomial will not reveal very useful information if not any at all.

[image: Scatter Plot with Connected Lines]

```
clf;
Start_Time = 5;
End_Time = 15;
Time_Interval = 0.25;
t = (Start_Time: Time_Interval: End_Time); 
y = rand(41,20);

for n = 1:20 
    plot(t,y(:,n),'.-'); 
    hold on 
end

Legend_Labels = "Data 1";
for Dataset_Index = 2: size(y,2)
   Legend_Labels = [Legend_Labels "Data "+num2str(Dataset_Index)];    
end

Current_Figure = gcf;
Current_Figure.Position = [50 50 1000 400];
title("Plotting Random Data with Respect to Time");
legend(Legend_Labels,'Location','EastOutside','Orientation','vertical');
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Value");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**